# Как с интерфейса (JAVA)добавлять в базу данных информацию

Tags: java, база-данных

Я написала программу школьный журнал. И мне нужно через интерфейс туда добавить класс(Пример "3Б").

Работа с базой данных в JAVA

```
package school.database;

import school.database.Grade;
import school.database.SchoolClass;
import school.database.Student;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DatabaseDAO {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "123456";

    private static final String GET_ALL_CLASSES_QUERY =
            "SELECT id, name FROM class ORDER BY name";

    private static final String GET_STUDENTS_IN_CLASS_QUERY =
            "SELECT * FROM student WHERE class_id = ?";

    private static final String GET_STUDENT_GRADES_QUERY =
            "SELECT s.name, gv.values, g.grade_date, t.fullname\n" +
                    "FROM grade g JOIN subject s\n" +
                    "ON g.subject_id = s.id\n" +
                    "JOIN student st\n" +
                    "ON g.student_id = st.id\n" +
                    "JOIN grade_value gv\n" +
                    "ON g.grade_id = gv.id\n" +
                    "JOIN teacher t\n" +
                    "ON g.teacher_id = t.id\n" +
                    "WHERE st.id = ?";

    private static final String PUT_CLASS_IN_QUERY = "INSERT INTO class (name) VALUES (?)";

    private Connection conn;

    public DatabaseDAO() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<SchoolClass> readAllClassesFromDB() {
        ArrayList<SchoolClass> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(GET_ALL_CLASSES_QUERY)) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                SchoolClass schoolClass = new SchoolClass(id, name);
                result.add(schoolClass);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> readStudentsInClassFromDB(int classID) {
        ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(GET_STUDENTS_IN_CLASS_QUERY)) {
            stmt.setInt(1, classID);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int studentID = rs.getInt("id");
                String firstName = rs.getString("name");
                String lastName = rs.getString("surname");
                Date birthday = rs.getDate("birthday");
                Student student = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, "PATRON", birthday);
                result.add(student);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<Grade> readGradesFromDB(int studentID) {
        ArrayList<Grade> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(GET_STUDENT_GRADES_QUERY)) {
            stmt.setInt(1, studentID);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String subject = rs.getString("name");
                int value = rs.getInt("values");
                java.util.Date date = rs.getDate("grade_date");
                String teacher = rs.getString("fullname");
                Grade grade = new Grade(subject, value, date);
                grade.setTeacher(teacher);
                result.add(grade);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return result;
    }



    public boolean writeClassinDB(Class clazz) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(PUT_CLASS_IN_QUERY);

            stmt.setString(1,  clazz.getName());

            if(stmt.executeUpdate() == 1){

        result = true;
            } 

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [INSERT в JAVA (SQL)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/941789/204271)

Comment: Нет там я другое спрашивала

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте метод `createSchoolClass(SchoolClass)` в `DatabaseDAO`, который внутри будет делать запрос на добавление в БД. В интерфейсе из слушателя нажатия кнопки `done` вызывайте созданный метод `createSchoolClass(SchoolClass)`, в качестве параметра укажите

```
done.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
        try {
            if (numsBox.getSelectedItem() != null && lettersBox.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                databaseDAO.createSchoolClass(new SchoolClass(0, "" + (Integer) numsBox.getSelectedItem() + (Character) lettersBox.getSelectedItem()));
                dispose();
            }
        } catch (KeyAlreadyExistsException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Класс " + e.getMessage() + " уже существует");
        }
    });
```

Comment: можете скинуть свой gmail я там уже создала я вам проект отправлю посмотрите просто там много классов

Comment: Я добавила интерфейс посмотрите

Comment: У меня сейчас нет доступа к почте. У вас не получилось добавить запись в БД? Или у вас есть другие вопросы?

Comment: не получилось добавить

Comment: я там добавила еще код\

Comment: Вы не могли бы актуализировать код  DatabaseDAO и CreateClassFrame и выложите, пожалуйста, класс Main, т.к. вы на него ссылаетесь в слушателе Main.addClass(...)

Comment: выложила сюда ))

Answer (score 0):

Все я нашла ответ

```
public void insertClassIntoDB(SchoolClass schoolClass) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt =
                conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_CLASS_QUERY, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {

            stmt.setString(1, String.valueOf(schoolClass.getNumber()) + schoolClass.getLetter());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

            if (keys.next()) {
                schoolClass.setId(keys.getInt(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void deleteClassFromDB(SchoolClass schoolClass) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(DELETE_CLASS_QUERY)) {
            stmt.setInt(1, schoolClass.getId());
            int rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```